# How to Convert String(yyyy-mm-dd) to date format

Tags: blackberry-jde

I have find the date in (yyyy-mm-dd) format Like this 2011-09-20.
Please give me the solution to convert this string to Date.

I want to add this date to the calender event in blackberry.

Comment: How did you find the date in String format? From where did you get it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question. If you are trying to get the current date, use this code:

```
java.util.Date today = new java.util.Date();
```

to get the current date, then use

```
today.toString()
```

to get the info such as day, month, and year. (Check out the BlackBerry API's for this)

If you are trying to set a date object, I would probably use Calendar.

Here is an example of my code where I create a Calendar object based on a specified date, then add it to the BlackBerry calendar

```
PIM pim = PIM.getInstance();
            try {

                String _date = date.getText();
                int _month  = Integer.parseInt(_date.substring(0, _date.indexOf('/')));
                _date = _date.substring(_date.indexOf('/') + 1);
                int _day = Integer.parseInt(_date.substring(0, _date.indexOf('/')));
                _date = _date.substring(_date.indexOf('/') + 1);
                int _year = Integer.parseInt(_date.substring(0, _date.indexOf('/')));
                _year = _year + 2000;

                EventList events = (EventList) pim.openPIMList(PIM.EVENT_LIST, PIM.READ_WRITE);
                Event event = events.createEvent();
                event.addString(Event.SUMMARY, PIMItem.ATTR_NONE, title.getText());
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, _year);

                //this of course seems like a terrible way to set the months, but the BlackBerry
                //api wants the month in this format
                if(_month == 1)
                    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JANUARY);
                if(_month == 2)
                    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.FEBRUARY);
                if(_month == 3)
                    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.MARCH);
                if(_month == 4)
                    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.APRIL);
                if(_month == 5)
                    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.MAY);
                if(_month == 6)
                    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JUNE);
                if(_month == 7)
                    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JULY);
                if(_month == 8)
                    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.AUGUST);
                if(_month == 9)
                    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.SEPTEMBER);
                if(_month == 10)
                    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.OCTOBER);
                if(_month == 11)
                    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.NOVEMBER);
                if(_month == 12)
                    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.DECEMBER);


                cal.set(Calendar.DATE, _day);
                cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 17);
                cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 15);

                event.addDate(Event.START, PIMItem.ATTR_NONE, cal.getTime().getTime());
                cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 21);

                event.addDate(Event.END, PIMItem.ATTR_NONE, cal.getTime().getTime());
                event.addString(BlackBerryEvent.LOCATION, PIMItem.ATTR_NONE, address.getText());
                event.addString(Event.NOTE, PIMItem.ATTR_NONE, description.getText());

                event.commit();

                Dialog.alert(title.getText() + " was added to your calendar.");

            } catch (PIMException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Good Luck!